# SQL Server Filter items for a user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a order table and an orderItem table. I would like to get orders for a user which are placed less than or
equal to 2 mins between them and who have the same products(number of products must match as well) associated to 
them.

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784065/using-sql-server-2012-lag) I'm able to sucessfully filter out order which are placed <=2 mins apart for a user. But I'm unable to figure out how to be able to get orders for a user which have same products associated to them as well.

I am expecting an output like

```
OrderNumber  OrderDateTime             UserId
1111         April, 28 2012 09:00:00     1
3333         April, 28 2012 09:03:00     1
4444         April, 28 2012 09:40:00     2
5555         April, 28 2012 09:42:00     2
```

Here is what I have tried so far: [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d0967/1/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your SQL Fiddle, I came up with this...

```
with Ordered as (
  select
    OrderNumber,
    OrderDateTime,
    UserId,
    LAG(OrderDateTime,1) over (
      partition by UserId
      order by OrderDateTime
    ) as prev_time,
    LEAD(OrderDateTime,1) over (
      partition by UserId
      order by OrderDateTime
    ) as next_time,
    LAG(OrderNumber,1) over (
      partition by UserId
      order by OrderDateTime
    ) as prev_OrderNumber,
    LEAD(OrderNumber,1) over (
      partition by UserId
      order by OrderDateTime
    ) as next_OrderNumber
  from [Order]
),
PossibleDuplicateOrders as (
  SELECT  OrderNumber,
          OrderDateTime,
          UserId,
          CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,OrderDateTime,next_time) <= 2 THEN next_OrderNumber
            WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,prev_time,OrderDateTime) <= 2 THEN prev_OrderNumber
            ELSE null
          END as DuplicateOrderNumber
  FROM Ordered
  WHERE   DATEDIFF(MINUTE,OrderDateTime,next_time) <= 2  --this says if the next value is less than or equal to two minutes away return it
          OR DATEDIFF(MINUTE,prev_time,OrderDateTime) <= 2 --this says if the prev value is less than or equal to 2 minutes away return it
)
select * 
  from  PossibleDuplicateOrders PDO
  where NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM   Order_Item OI_Left
      LEFT JOIN Order_Item OI_Right 
             ON OI_Right.OrderNumber = PDO.DuplicateOrderNumber 
            AND OI_Right.ProductID = OI_Left.ProductID
      WHERE  OI_Left.OrderNumber = PDO.OrderNumber
      AND    OI_Right.ProductID is NULL
    )
  and NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM   Order_Item OI_Left
      LEFT JOIN Order_Item OI_Right 
             ON OI_Right.OrderNumber = PDO.OrderNumber 
            AND OI_Right.ProductID = OI_Left.ProductID
      WHERE  OI_Left.OrderNumber = PDO.DuplicateOrderNumber
      AND    OI_Right.ProductID is NULL
    )
```

From what I can see, only orders 4444 and 5555 should be considered duplicates by your criteria.  (within 2 minutes of each other and have matching items.)  Your SQL Fiddle did not include quantities, so I did not include them in my query, but you can add them in if you need them.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer, I want to have 4444 and 5555 in two separate rows, I don't care about the duplicateOrderNumber column.Is that possible?

Comment: The problem with that is knowing what order numbers to join on.  My suggestion would be to take the results from this query and either select the OrderNumber column UNIONed with the DuplicateOrderNumber column, or UNPIVOT the results.